# Merge [highlight] and [highlighting]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

A while ago I suggested that [highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlight) would get the synonym [highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlighting), through the [tag synonyms feature](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/highlight/synonyms). As I still feel they are duplicates, I'll try bringing attention to it here.

[highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlight): •Tag wiki ✔ •Questions tagged: 2,078 questions

> is for questions involving the highlighting of text or other visual elements.

[highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlighting): •Tag wiki ✔ •Questions tagged: 919 questions

> Attract attention to or emphasize something important eg. by making chosen words or phrases more visually prominent.

In my opinion they are synonymous and should be joined.